# How can I adjust the height of a contentView to the height of a UITableViewCell?

Tags: swift, uitableview, subview

I want to make a tableView with custom tableViewCells in Swift. I set the row height to 70.0 points.

```
        tableView.rowHeight = 70.0
```

This part works perfectly fine. But when I tried to add a subview to the contentView of my cell, I noticed that it only has a height of 44.0 points. How can I adjust the contentView's height to my tableViewCell's height?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could figure out what was missing. In reality it's easy to do.
In the init() method of my cell class I had to add this line:

```
contentView.frame = cellFrame
```

I also had to add a parameter to the init() method because it gets cellFrame from the TableViewDelegate.

Answer (score 1):

Try with autoresizing mask property on your custom cell. Subview which you have added now apply autoresizing mask property on custom cell and subview. Give dynamic height and width. Also give autoresizing mask property to your tableview. So that will make maximum High width table and custom cell that will fit in all device UI.

Comment: How can I do this?